# Automated testing of installation process for Google Marketplace app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Is there any easy way to repeatedly test the installation process of a Google Marketplace App on a new domain?  It seems as though when you try to install an app to a domain to which it's already been installed, parts of the process are short-circuited, even if the app's permissions on that domain have been revoked.  Is there any way around this short of registering a throwaway domain for every test?  Being able to automate this test would be even better, but even a repeatable manual test would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to delete the application and install it again each time from what I gather.

You can revoke the auth here: https://www.google.com/a/your-domain-here/IssuedAuthSubTokens

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to register throwaway domains every time.

If you're trying to test your integration, there is "TEST INSTALL FLOW' button right in the Google APIs Console that starts a test flow. Here's a screenshot:
[image: Test install flow]

That's especially useful when you want to test your integration before it is published to the Google Apps Marketplace (but it still works once it is published.)

If you actually install it from the Marketplace as a tester or once published, you can go to the app listing and remove the app. Since we've launched I've added and removed my apps that way quite a few times :) Here's a screenshot:

[image]

@aleckz suggestion won't actually work since tokens are Admin authorized and not revokable by the domain user.

Comment: I've been clearing it to simulate a user logging in for the first time with their Google account. My understanding is that with the new marketplace users must consent the first time. If this isn't cleared you won't get a refresh_token during initial setup.

Comment: Not quite. When an admin installs an app for their domain, they are pre-approving that app to generate access tokens. If done correctly, the domain users should never see a dialog. We also do not yet support refresh tokens so there isn't anything to revoke. If you're seeing a dialog than SSO isn't set up correctly.

Comment: Seems there's so much conflicting information. Is there a way to contact Google for support? Don't mind paying for it...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no paid support. I work for Google so I can do my best to help you. First I'd like to help unblock you and then figure out where we can clarify any misinformation.